# Same RegEx validation works on the server side but not on client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

I am using ASP.Net MVC to validate  that a string will not contain more than 2 numbers in any form.

I'm using the following server side code:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*",ErrorMessage = "More than 2 Numbers are not allowed")]
```

That works great, but the following JavaScript code will always return `0`:

```
>> var mystring = "test123"; 
>> var myregax = new RegExp("[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*"); 
>> mystring.search(myregax); 
0 
>> mystring = "test"; 
"test" 
>> mystring.search(myregax); 
0
```

What am I missing and what is the difference between the regular expression syntax of ASP.Net and JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  `RegExp` object you have to escape the `\` in your pattern

```
new RegExp("[^\\d]*\\d?[^\\d]*\\d?[^\\d]*");
```

or, as alternative, use this syntax

```
var myregax = /[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*/;
```

Comment: for some reason that is still not working (will always return 0) any idea why?

Comment: use `myregax.test("test123");` or provide a jsfiddle/jsbin example

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Fabrizio Calderan's answer, which is entirely correct, you are using [`search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

`search()` returns the starting index of the first match, which is `0` since the entire string matches the regex. You should be calling [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead, which returns a boolean if the regex matches or not.

Edit: a regex like [this](http://regexr.com?329q1):

`/\D*\d{1}\D*\d{1}\D*/`

Would return `true` for anything that has two or more numbers, so your condition would be:

```
if (/\D*\d{1}\D*\d{1}\D*/.test(string)) {
    // 2 or more numbers, validation failed
} else {
    // less than 2 numbers, validation passed
}
```

Comment: then i guess something is worng with my expresstion becuase it still always return true:var myregax = /[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*/; 
>> myregax.test("test123");

Comment: @python yes, your regex matches anything, what are you trying to accomplish? http://regexr.com?329po

Comment: to allow only 2 numbers in the string (no matter in what format), but the funny thing is that on server side with the RegularExpression attribute it works perfectly so why on js it doesn't?

Comment: @python see my edit - i think your condition is just backwards.

Comment: it simply works, big thanks for all the proccess :) will upvote now

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring = "test123";
var filter=/[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*\d?[^\d]*/
if(filter.test(mystring)) {
alert("true");
} else {
alert("false");
}
```